# NameError: name 'run_once' is not defined in python

Tags: python

Python: 3.8.1

I wanted to run a method only once in my class. I have learned the following ways of achieving things and worked well.

```
def run_once():
    # Code for something you only want to execute once
    print("test")
    run_once.__code__ = (lambda: None).__code__
    return "Success"


print(run_once())
print(run_once())
print(run_once())
```

Output:- --> Expected and Actual

```
test
Success
None
None
```

Apparently, getting an error while trying to achieving the same via static method in a class.

```
class testing():

    @staticmethod
    def run_once(data):
        # Code for something you only want to execute once
        print(data)
        run_once("").__code__ = (lambda: None).__code__
        return "Success"


print(testing.run_once("test"))
```

**Trackback:-**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo/test.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(testing.run_once("test"))
  File "foo/test.py", line 7, in run_once
    run_once("").__code__ = (lambda: None).__code__
NameError: name 'run_once' is not defined
test
```

Could someone highlight where changes required to be made?

Comment: You always have to refer to your static method as `testing.run_once` so change line 7. This is because once the definition is inside the class `run_once` isn’t defined in the global scope.

Comment: You could achieve the same objective in simpler ways - for example using a function variable and a simple `if` statement to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define `run_once` as a static method inside the testing class it must be referenced as `testing.run_once`, since `run_once` does not exists outside that class.

```py
class testing():
    @staticmethod
    def run_once(data):
        # Code for something you only want to execute once
        print(data)
        testing.run_once.__code__ = (lambda x: None).__code__
        return "Success"
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to write these lines of code is:

```
class testing():

    @staticmethod
    def run_once(data):
        # Code for something you only want to execute once
        print(data)
        testing.run_once("").__code__ = (lambda: None).__code__
        return "Success"
print(testing.run_once("test"))
```

Culprit line is `run_once("").__code__ = (lambda: None).__code__` that is to be replaced with `testing.run_once("").__code__ = (lambda: None).__code__`. Howeveer it will also not solve the problem because now you are calling class function within the class that will cause `exceeds the maxium limits` error. Pleas try to improve your logic in this case. It is more about logical problem then syntax.

Correct logic and syntax will be:

```
class testing():
    @staticmethod
    def run_once(data):
        # Code for something you only want to execute once
        print(data)
        testing.run_once.__code__ = (lambda x: None).__code__
        return "Success"
print(testing.run_once("test"))
```